# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder", nothing helps

Tags: java, drools, slf4j

I created default Drools project, tried to launch it, but I have this error:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

what's wrong? I didn't change anything in project. Btw I have no pom.xml file, should I create one?
I checked some solutions, but nothing helps, please help

Answer (score 2):

Add a runtime dependency to `logback-classic`. Or if you don't use maven/gradle/etc, then add the logback-classic jar in your classpath.

```
<!-- Logging -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

See http://www.slf4j.org for more information and other options.

Comment: I use maven, how can I add a runtime dependency to logback-classic?

Comment: still doesn't work, where should my pom.xml file be?

Answer (score 0):

add This in POM.xml file as a dependency, clean and build your project again and run !! This should solve the problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Duplicate answer. A almost similar answer is given previously in the thread